# Chromedriver thread persists even after app crash. how to prevent it?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I have  driver.close() and driver.quit() in my code but sometimes app gets crashed and those drivers, chrome.exe and conhosts are still open...
I do not have any idea how to prevent it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MetroFramework.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Diagnostics;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : MetroForm
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private ChromeOptions option;
        private List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();

        public Form1()
        {
            option = new ChromeOptions();
            option.AddArgument("--headless --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36");

            InitializeComponent();
            LoadEngines();

        }

        private void LoadEngines() {
            List<string[]> lista = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Redirect\sites.txt")
                                      .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                                      .ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++)
            {
                engines.Text += lista[i][0]+ "\r\n";
            }
            list = lista;

        }
        private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
            service.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
            if (inL.Text != String.Empty) {
                List<string> inUrls = new List<string>(
                               inL.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" },
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

                Debug.WriteLine(inUrls[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                status.Text = "Enter Urls";
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                driver = new ChromeDriver(service, option);
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);


                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(list[i][0]);
                        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(list[i][1])).SendKeys("http://google.com");
                        driver.FindElement(By.XPath(list[i][2])).Click();
                        outL.Text += driver.FindElement(By.XPath(list[i][3])).GetAttribute(list[i][4]) + "\r\n";
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchElementException err)
                    {
                        Logs.Text += $"No such element: {err} could be found.";
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
                ss.SaveAsFile("C://Image.png",
                ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                driver.Close();
                driver.Quit();
                driver.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }


    }
```

Edited: So I have added code, maybe it will help to fix my test.
I need to automatically  close  chromedriver.exe and chrome.exe after every run.
Is remote server a good solutions?

Comment: Can you show us `InitializeComponent()`? Can you show us how `metroButton1_Click()` is invoked? Any reason to use `ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();` and `ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();` both?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the chromedriver.exe thread should get purged after `driver.quit()` call. In case , if it doesn't you can invoke system level commands to do the job. You can create a batch file with the following code :

```
@echo off
rem   just killing stray local chromedriver.exe instances.
taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f
```

In your C# code, call this bat at the end of test suite :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:\\batchfilename.bat");
```

Comment: Why would he create batch file if the System.Diagnostics.Process class contains a Kill method?